# Solution to the following system of linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

My textbook gives the following system,
\begin{matrix} 
4-  x_2 -x_3+x_4 =0 \\
x_1 +x_2+x_3+x_4 = 6\\
2x_1 +4x_2+x_3-2x_4 = -1\\
3x_1 +x_2-2x_3+2x_4 = 3 
\end{matrix}

and supplies the answer as $$(2,-1,3,2)$$They set up the augmented matrix as follows,

$$\left[\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
0 & -1 &-1&1& 0 \\
1 &  1 & 1&1&6\\
2 & 4 &1&-2&-1\\
3 & 1 &-2&2&3
\end{array}\right]$$
The solution checks out for all the equations except the first one. Why is this correct ?

Comment: the (1, 1) element differs.

Comment: It appears the initial $4$ should be a zero.

Comment: Yeah just found the errata for the textbook. The 4 was suppose to be a 0. If the 4 were suppose to be there, how would you set up the augmented matrix ?

Comment: The augmented matrix and solution are already correct. Only the first equation had a mistake.

Comment: @AMPerrine Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in the first equation of the system. If the four is replaced with a zero then both the augmented matrix and solution will be correct.